# FME Features to read parameter

Tags: fme-form, microstation

I would like to ask if there is a way in FME to set the Feature types to read parameter, from values in microsoft access table. I have a model that translates .dgn files and  then appends them to a SQL table to use in ArcMap, but the model at this moment is hard-coded to  specific level numbers, and it needs to be able to change these levels according to access tables that are provided by the engineers.

Comment: Use the 'Dynamic Schema with scripted parameters' http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Pass-a-List-of-Tables-or-Layers-to-an-FME-Reader-using-Python-Scripted-Parameters

Comment: Use Feature Reader Transformer and TestFilter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, read the access table and concatenate the feature types to read into a single attribute. Then use the FeatureReader transformer. It will let you define the Feature Types to Read using that attribute.

The other alternative is to use a scripted parameter to read the file contents and pass them on to the FTTR parameter. But, since it's an Access file and not plain text, I think this would end up being harder to do.

Answer (score 0):

I do it from excel file by reading all lines in as feature , then using featureMerger to merge dgn line color to excel table where data that color xxx means that it should have yyy value.  Featuremerge is in Attributes only mode. Fme supports MsAccess reader